# How to write a 'from clause' in django?

Tags: django

Suppose there are two models m1 and m2, and now we need to run a query equal to "SELECT * FROM m1, m2" in django. How to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you realise that the SQL you've posted produces a cartesian join between the tables m1 and m2? That is, your result set includes all possible rows from m1 joined with all possible rows from m2, so if you have 5 rows in one table and 10 in another, you'll get 50 results.

If that's really what you want, and I can't think why you would, there's no easy way to do it in the Django ORM.

However, if what you actually meant was a simple JOIN:

```
SELECT * from m1, m2 WHERE m1.m2_id = m2.id;
```

then you can achieve something similar with the [`select_related()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) method.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

<strike>m1.objects.all() + m2.objects.all()</strike>

```
list(m1.objects.all()) + list(m2.objects.all())
```

But.. Daniel Roseman has a very good point about Cartesian product - if that's what you meant.

Comment: This will fail unless m1 and m2 are the same model. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It's a simple list addition, it can't fail.

Comment: -1. Querysets aren't lists. This will fail - actually, it will fail even if they're the same model, as the QuerySet class simply doesn't define the `__add__` method.

Comment: Yes, I typed out of the top of my head, forgetting to wrap QuerySets in list()-s. But I admit I didn't realize that there was a M1*M2 product involved.